# proper code for onCreate, on Resume for activity-interaction in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

For example, we have 2 activities: Main - libgdx and Aux - Android normal Activity.

In Main, we have a button to go to Aux( read and follow [this](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup) instruction ), and a button in Aux to return to Main.

My startActivity code:

```
@Override
public void startActivity(Class<?> C) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, C);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    appContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

When we go from Main to Aux, it's OK, but when we return, it just show a blank WHITE screen( it still interact with player but doesn't show anything):((.

Could you please help me a proper way to solve this?

P/S: Currently I leave onCreate and onResume, etc... blank.

Comment: Why did you override the startActivity method? it the a reason to do so?

Comment: Please see the link above, libgdx interacts with Android through an ActionResolver class, and it doesn't extends anything.

Comment: when going back to libgdx you will need to reload your textures in resume.

Comment: Thank a lot! But could you please explain in more detail with an answer? I have lots of textures and manage with AssetManager, Is there a need to reload all?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is OpenGLES context loss.

As of today, libgdx v0.9.9 [Textures](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html) are managed, this means they will be reloaded automatically in case of context loss. If you created them like this:

```
texture = new Texture(...);
```

If not, then you have to reload them manually.